# Can you map the power set of the (set of) positive integers onto $[0,1]$? Show a measure from the power set of the positive integers = $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $\mathbb{Z}^+$ be the set of all positive integers. For any $k \in  \mathbb{Z}^+$, let function $w(k) = 2^{-k}$. Moreover, let $E$ denote an element of the power set of $\mathbb{Z}^+$, that is, $E \in 2^{\mathbb{Z}^+}$. I define the function $f(E): 2^{\mathbb{Z}^+} \rightarrow [0,1] = \sum_{k \in E} w(k)= \sum_{k \in E} 2^{-k}$.

How can I show that for *every* element in $[0,1]$, say, $a$, there exists an $E$ for which $f(E)=\sum_{k \in E} w(k)=a$?

Here is my try (edited, based on Arturo's comment below). Could you please briefly check my proof?

*Every* $a \in [0,1]$ has a binary representation (not necessarily unique) of the form $a = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\,w_k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\,2^{-k}$, where every $a_k \in \{0,1\}$. Choosing the right representation, for all $a \in [0,1]$, there exists a set $E_a=\{k \in \mathbb{Z}^+ : a_k = 1\}$. $E_a \subset \mathbb{Z}^+$. As we find an $E_a \in 2^{\mathbb{Z}^+}$ for every $a \in [0,1]$, we know that $f(E)$ is onto $[0,1]$. Moreover, $f(E) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\,2^{-k} = \sum_{k \in E} 2^{-k} = a$.

For a measure, we need two properties. (I) $f(\emptyset)= 0$. This is the case as $f(\emptyset)=\sum_{k \in \emptyset} w(k)=0$. (II) $F\left(\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k \right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty F(E_k)$ for a disjoint sequence $E_k$.

Comment: Use binary representation.

Comment: Thank you, Arturo, I edited my question and tried to spell out what you probably have in mind.

Comment: The title should be rephrased: Can you map the power set of the (set of) positive integers onto $[0,1]$?

Comment: Just a minor detail. Some $a\in[0,1]$ have **two** binary representations. To correctly define the set $E_a$ you should specify which one are you choosing.

Comment: @jjagmath, Thank you, I agree. But for showing that my $f(E)$ is onto, I think that it is fine when we have **two** binary representations. The function is then not one-to-one. Thus, the set $E_a$ is not uniquely determined, which is not so much of a question in my (overall) problem.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sure, thank you. In fact, there is a bigger problem behind the question, though everything depends on the answer to the "trivial" question.

Comment: If you choose the wrong representation for $a=1$ then $E_a$ doesn't exists.

Comment: @RonW It would be good to give the bigger problem as well, to provide better context for this question and shape the information in the answers you get.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Sure. The bigger question was one in measure theory (Axler, Section 2C). Give an example of a measure on $(\mathbb{Z}^+, 2^{\mathbb{Z}^+})$, for which the set of the measures of all subsets of $2^{\mathbb{Z}^+}$ = $[0,1]$.